# I have 2 worksheets in which I need to colour the entire row based on the value in cell 9 of that row

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets which have the same structure, however they are capturing different data. When data is entered into the 9th cell, I want the the colour of the entire row to change according to a list that is set up on a separate sheet. The same list is to be used for both worksheets - with the same colours required. There are 14 options in the list.

I found a response to another question which enables me to get this to work on 1 worksheet, but was hoping that it could be amended to be used across both sheets. One sheet is called "Operations Review Register". The other is "Support Review Register". The list is in a sheet called "Validation Data"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10053946

This is what I have so far - from the previous response.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Changed As Range)

  Dim CellCrnt As Variant
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim Found As Boolean
  Dim MonitorColNum As Long
  Dim MonitorSheetName As String
  Dim RowNCCrnt As Long

  MonitorSheetName = "Operations Review Register"
  MonitorColNum = 9

  ' So changes to monitored cells do not trigger this routine
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  If Sh.Name = MonitorSheetName Then
    ' Use last value in heading row to determine range to colour
    ColLast = Sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each CellCrnt In Changed
      If CellCrnt.Column = MonitorColNum Then
        With Worksheets("Validation Data")
          RowNCCrnt = 1
          Found = False
          Do While .Cells(RowNCCrnt, 1).Value <> ""
            If LCase(.Cells(RowNCCrnt, 1).Value) = LCase(CellCrnt.Value) Then
              ' Ensure standard case
              CellCrnt.Value = .Cells(RowNCCrnt, 1).Value
              ' Set required colour to name
              'CellCrnt.Interior.Color = .Cells(RowNCCrnt, 1).Interior.Color
              ' Set required colour to row
              Sh.Range(Sh.Cells(CellCrnt.Row, 1), _
                       Sh.Cells(CellCrnt.Row, ColLast)).Interior.Color = _
                                     .Cells(RowNCCrnt, 1).Interior.Color
              Found = True
              Exit Do
            End If
            RowNCCrnt = RowNCCrnt + 1
          Loop
          If Not Found Then
            ' Name not found.  Add to list so its colour can be specified later
            .Cells(RowNCCrnt, 1).Value = CellCrnt.Value
            ' Clear any existing colour
            Sh.Range(Sh.Cells(CellCrnt.Row, 1), _
                 Sh.Cells(CellCrnt.Row, ColLast)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
          End If
        End With
      End If
    Next
  End If

  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you
DB

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here. If you want it to apply to the current sheet, just remove the test for the sheet name (`If Sh.Name = MonitorSheetName Then`). If the behavior varies based on which sheet it is, add a second `if` for the other sheet name and write the code that works on it.

Answer (score 2):

When working with Sheet's Changed event, 2 things are a must.

**1)** Switching of `.EnableEvents` which you are already doing

**2)** Error handling to switch `.EnableEvents` back to `True`. If you don't then if you get an error the `.EnableEvents` will remain switched off and the above code will stop working.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Select Case Sh.Name
        Case "Operations Review Register", "Support Review Register"
            If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(9)) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False

                Dim Rng As Range, cl As Range, aCell As Range

                Set Rng = Sheets("Validation Data").Range("A1:A14")

                For Each cl In Target
                    If cl.Column = 9 Then
                        Set aCell = Rng.Find(What:=cl.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                            Sh.Rows(cl.Row).Interior.Color = _
                            aCell.Interior.Color
                        Else
                            Sh.Rows(cl.Row).Interior.Color = xlNone
                        End If                            
                    End If
                Next
            End If
    End Select

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to set `Application.ScreenUpdating` in the above code. Set it `False` and `True` as we did for `Application.EnableEvents`

Comment: +1 for the thorough answer including the best practices advice. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
If Sh.Name = MonitorSheetName Then
```

To this:

```
If Sh.Name = "Operations Review Register" Or Sh.Name = "Support Review Register" Then
```

Once you get it to work, you can replace the hard coded sheet names with variables.

Comment: + 1 Yup, the 2nd name was missing. :)